# How to get information about the current page of a paginated post in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress, pagination, word-count

Any suggestions on how I might get the word count of the current page of a paginated post in Wordpress?  And in general, how to get information about only the current page of a paginated post (paginated using "").

I've made a wordcount function based on this helpful blog post: http://bacsoftwareconsulting.com/blog/index.php/wordpress-cat/how-to-display-word-count-of-wordpress-posts-without-a-plugin/ but that gets me the total word count for the entire post, not the count for the current page only.

Thanks much for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use [`$wp_query`](http://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query) to access the post's content and the current page number, then split the post's content into the pages using PHP's [`explode()`](http://php.net/manual/function.explode.php), strip all HTML-tags from the content using [`strip_tags()`](http://php.net/manual/function.strip-tags.php), because they don't count as words and finally count the words of just the current page with [`str_word_count()`](http://php.net/manual/function.str-word-count.php).

```
function paginated_post_word_count() {
    global $wp_query;

    // $wp_query->post->post_content is only available during the loop
    if( empty( $wp_query->post ) )
        return;

    // Split the current post's content into an array with the content of each page as an item
    $post_pages = explode( "<!--nextpage-->", $wp_query->post->post_content );

    // Determine the current page; because the array $post_pages starts with index 0, but pages
    // start with 1, we need to subtract 1
    $current_page = ( isset( $wp_query->query_vars['page'] ) ? $wp_query->query_vars['page'] : 1 ) - 1;

    // Count the words of the current post
    $word_count = str_word_count( strip_tags( $post_pages[$current_page] ) );

    return $word_count;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You will have to count words of all the posts on the page.  Assuming this is inside the loop, you can define a global variable initialized to zero and then count the words displayed in each post using the method suggested in the link you have posted.

Something on this lines -

```
$word_count = 0;

if ( have_posts() ) : while ( have_posts() ) : the_post();
    global $word_count;
    $word_count += str_word_count(strip_tags($post->post_excerpt), 0, ' ');
endwhile;
endif;
```

Comment: I think what @alison wanted, was to count the words of just ONE page of a paginated post `<!--nextpage-->`, not of every post.